# Pakistani asylum seekers in Europe

Tags: germany, pakistani-citizen, asylum

If someone pakistan citizens have life sentence or life penalty in his home country mean pakistan because he is did murder of one person  then he can apply for asylum in europe and how many chance for qualify then he have all type of avidence me FIR

Answer (score 1):

The chance of qualifying for asylum will vary greatly depending on the circumstances.  Being sought on murder charges is probably unlikely to help unless the person has good evidence that the charges are unjustified.

If the charges are in fact justified then the asylum claim will probably not succeed.  For example, the [1951 refugee convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_Relating_to_the_Status_of_Refugees) does not apply to anyone

> ...with respect to whom there are serious reasons for considering that ... he has committed a serious non-political crime outside the country of refuge prior to his admission to that country as a refugee;

However, the decision on the asylum claim will be made by the country in which he applies for asylum, under that country's domestic law.  The chance of success therefore will also vary depending on the country where asylum is sought.

Comment: While being technically correct, I don't see how Pakistan would not file an international arrest warrant for people who are **convicted** murderers and on the run.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence, I have to look up this film again. Some reporters wanted to do a piece about young men fleeing from Afghanistan. They found two, and followed their way through Iran and Turkey. Then, at the Turkish west coast, one of them was missing. They followed the remaining man to Paris. Later, they found out the other young man was charged for murder in his home country, Afghanistan, and the police in Turkey knew about that, so they arrested him and brought him back into an Afghan prison.

Comment: @Janka sure, but the existence of an international arrest warrant wouldn't change anything. If the host country judged that the charges constituted persecution, they would grant asylum and not honor the warrant. Otherwise, they'd return the person to Pakistan even in the absence of a warrant (unless the person faced the death penalty; EU countries won't extradite people unless there is an assurance that the death penalty will not be imposed).

Comment: I posted the anecdote to show up the most obvious obstacle. You had to reach a European country first.

Comment: @Janka that is quite true.  I assumed that reaching the country was implicit in "can he apply for asylum in Europe," but it is not necessarily so.  If he cannot reach Europe, he cannot apply for asylum there.